# Block console for website while making addon for Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, console.log

there are already dozens of ways explained to disable the console.log function completely. I know... console.log = function() {} is probably the best known...

But what I could not find is a way to block a website´s script from accessing to the browser console totally while I still can use it. Also a lot of warnings appear in all sorts of scripts. And many pages just keep logging after developing. A really annoying example could be this site: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/plugincheck/

One answer is to filter the output for my add-on by hand in the console´s built in filter, but that is not good if the add-on itself doesn't work (e.g. due to script-errors, which prevent the add-on from working at all). Anyway I don´t want to fill in a filter every time I restart the browser.

So I would like to have a permanent way to suppress every output coming from a website (even warnings, errors etc.) without blocking my add-on from logging.

If possible without using jQuery :)
Any ideas?

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: Sorry. I have to ask. Why do you need to deny use of `console.log()` at all? If you only want the logs from your plug-in to be visible, many dev tools [include options to filter the console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console#Filtering_and_searching).

Comment: Well as I said: if I filter I can´t be sure, to see everything relevant. I don´t want to see only my add-on, but everything except the websites stuff. Sure: I could just uncheck JS-errors, but if my add-on then produces those errors I wouldn´t see them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Console²](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/console%C2%B2/) allows to filter chrome and content messages.